# A collection based on a bitset to store a set of unique integers from a given range (rev. 3)

Tags: c++, performance, collections, c++20, memory-optimization

All right, let's do this one last time.

This is continuation of [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289262/78158).
I applied most of the proposed changes, making interface of my container very close to that of `std::set`.
(I also added a few things that weren't explicitly mentioned but I found them on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). For example, some type definitions like `key_compare` and `value_compare` which to be honest I don't know if I need.)

**Description of the code:**

This is an implementation of a set data structure.
It is optimized to efficiently store a huge amount of unsigned integers (even billions) from a range specified at construction (it always starts at 0).
It it used in very expensive computations so the main goal of this implementation (beside the memory efficiency) is performance.

The most important (for my goals) properties of this set are random read/write access in O(1) time, checking its size in O(1) time and an iterator that can continue iteration after changes in the set are made.

Additionally, the set is kept sorted because of how it is implemented.

This collection is not intended for storing small number of integers from a huge possible range. In such case the memory optimization is terrible and iteration takes too long.
(This is not the case in my program where on average half of the integers from the range is in the set.)

**The goal of the review:**

In my opinion the code is pretty good and it may need a few finishing touches at the most.
However, that's what I was thinking the last time and you guys proved me very wrong.
Actually, I'm not sure if declaring a goal is all that productive. If I can think it before the review, I can probably find the problem without help. Tell me about things I didn't think about. Go nuts.

However, changes that sacrifice performance for clean code are still off limits.

**The code:**

[`CompactSet.hh`](https://github.com/piotrsiupa/karnaugh-solver/blob/fc6a6ce80d973153fa01607d1158351add9a6ad7/src/CompactSet.hh):

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


// This container can store unique numbers in range 0..capacity-1 using only about capacity/CHAR_BIT bytes of memory.
// (The memory usage is the same regardles of how many numbers are stored.)
template<std::unsigned_integral T>
class CompactSet
{
public:
    using key_type = T;
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::vector<bool>::size_type;
    using difference_type = std::vector<bool>::difference_type;
    using key_compare = std::less<key_type>;
    using value_compare = std::less<value_type>;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;
    
private:
    std::vector<bool> bits;
    size_type size_ = 0;
    
public:
    class iterator
    {
        const std::vector<bool> *bits = nullptr;
        size_type i;
        
        iterator(const std::vector<bool> &bits, const size_type i) : bits(&bits), i(i) { }
        friend class CompactSet<T>;
        
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        
        iterator() = default;
        
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const iterator &other) const { return this->i == other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i != other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator<(const iterator &other) const { return this->i < other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator<=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i <= other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator>(const iterator &other) const { return this->i > other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool operator>=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i >= other.i; }
        [[nodiscard]] auto operator<=>(const iterator &other) const { return this->i <=> other.i; }
        
        inline iterator& operator++();
        [[nodiscard]] iterator operator++(int) const { iterator copy = *this; ++copy; return copy; }
        inline iterator& operator--();
        [[nodiscard]] iterator operator--(int) const { iterator copy = *this; --copy; return copy; }
        
        [[nodiscard]] value_type operator*() const { return static_cast<value_type>(i); }
    };
    static_assert(std::bidirectional_iterator<iterator>);
    using const_iterator = iterator;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = reverse_iterator;
    
    explicit inline CompactSet(const size_type capacity);
    
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const CompactSet &other) const { return this->size_ == other.size_ && this->bits == other.bits; }
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(const CompactSet &other) const { return !(*this == other); }
    
    [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const { return size_ == 0; }
    [[nodiscard]] bool full() const { return size_ == bits.size(); }
    [[nodiscard]] size_type size() const { return size_; }
    [[nodiscard]] size_type max_size() const { return bits.size(); }
    
    void clear() { std::fill(bits.begin(), bits.end(), false); size_ = 0; }
    inline std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type value);
    iterator insert(const const_iterator, const value_type value) { return insert(value).first; }
    template<class InputIt>
    inline void insert(const InputIt first, const InputIt last);
    void insert(std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist) { return insert(ilist.begin(), ilist.end()); }
    inline void unsafe_insert(const CompactSet &other, const size_type overlappingCount);  // This is needed to cut off a few seconds at max input size.
    template<class... Args>
    std::pair<iterator, bool> emplace(Args&&... args) { return insert(value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
    template<class... Args>
    iterator emplace_hint(const const_iterator, Args&&... args) { return insert(value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...)).first; }
    inline iterator erase(const_iterator pos);
    inline iterator erase(const const_iterator first, const const_iterator last);
    inline size_type erase(const value_type value);
    void swap(CompactSet &other) { std::ranges::swap(this->bits, other.bits); std::ranges::swap(this->size_, other.size_); }
    
    [[nodiscard]] size_type count(const value_type value) const { return bits[value] ? 1 : 0; }
    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator find(const value_type value) const { return bits[value] ? iterator(bits, value) : end(); }
    [[nodiscard]] bool contains(const value_type value) const { return bits[value]; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline std::pair<const_iterator, const_iterator> equal_range(const value_type value) const;
    [[nodiscard]] inline const_iterator lower_bound(const value_type value) const;
    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator upper_bound(const value_type value) const;
    
    [[nodiscard]] inline const_iterator begin() const;
    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator end() const { return {this->bits, bits.size()}; }
    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }
    [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end()); }
    [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator rend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return rbegin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return rend(); }
    
#ifndef NDEBUG
    void validate() const;
#endif
};


template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator& CompactSet<T>::iterator::operator++()
{
    for (++i; i != bits->size() && !(*bits)[i]; ++i) { }
    return *this;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator& CompactSet<T>::iterator::operator--()
{
    for (--i; !(*bits)[i]; --i) { }
    return *this;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
CompactSet<T>::CompactSet(const size_type capacity) :
    bits(capacity, false)
{
    assert(capacity == 0 || capacity - 1 <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    assert(capacity <= std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max());  // Otherwise, iterators won't work.
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
std::pair<typename CompactSet<T>::iterator, bool> CompactSet<T>::insert(const value_type value)
{
    const bool previous = bits[value];
    if (!previous)
    {
        bits[value] = true;
        ++size_;
    }
    return {{this->bits, value}, !previous};
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
template<class InputIt>
void CompactSet<T>::insert(const InputIt first, const InputIt last)
{
    for (InputIt current = first; current != last; ++current)
        insert(*current);
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
void CompactSet<T>::unsafe_insert(const CompactSet &other, const size_type overlappingCount)
{
    std::transform(
            other.bits.cbegin(), other.bits.cend(),
            this->bits.begin(), this->bits.begin(),
            std::logical_or<bool>());
    this->size_ += other.size_ - overlappingCount;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator CompactSet<T>::erase(const_iterator pos)
{
    bits[*pos] = false;
    --size_;
    ++pos;
    return pos;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator CompactSet<T>::erase(const const_iterator first, const const_iterator last)
{
    for (const_iterator current = first; current != last; ++current)
    {
        bits[*current] = false;
        --size_;
    }
    return last;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::size_type CompactSet<T>::erase(const value_type value)
{
    const bool previous = bits[value];
    if (previous)
    {
        bits[value] = false;
        --size_;
    }
    return previous ? 1 : 0;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
std::pair<typename CompactSet<T>::iterator, typename CompactSet<T>::iterator> CompactSet<T>::equal_range(const value_type value) const
{
    iterator iter(bits, value);
    if (bits[value])
        return {iter, std::ranges::next(iter)};
    ++iter;
    return {iter, iter};
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator CompactSet<T>::lower_bound(const value_type value) const
{
    iterator iter(bits, value);
    if (!bits[value])
        ++iter;
    return iter;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator CompactSet<T>::upper_bound(const value_type value) const
{
    iterator iter(bits, value);
    return ++iter;
}

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
typename CompactSet<T>::iterator CompactSet<T>::begin() const
{
    iterator iter{this->bits, 0};
    if (!bits.empty() && !bits[0])
        ++iter;
    return iter;
}
```

[`CompactSet.cc`](https://github.com/piotrsiupa/karnaugh-solver/blob/fc6a6ce80d973153fa01607d1158351add9a6ad7/src/CompactSet.cc):

```cpp
#include "./CompactSet.hh"


#ifndef NDEBUG
template<std::unsigned_integral T>
void CompactSet<T>::validate() const
{
    const std::size_t actualCount = std::ranges::count(bits, true);
    assert(size_ == actualCount);
}
#endif


#include "Minterm.hh"

template class CompactSet<Minterm>;
```

The function `validate()` is called (in development build only) to make sure mostly that the `unsafe_insert()` was correctly used and in lesser degree to also check if normal `insert()` and `erase()` are working correctly.

`Minterm` (an alias for `std::uint_fast32_t`) is the only type for which this class is used in my code.

Comment: Here are the files after applying changes from the review: https://github.com/piotrsiupa/karnaugh-solver/blob/530bc70277779e81b4c666e7608a048a3b568df3/src/CompactSet.hh & https://github.com/piotrsiupa/karnaugh-solver/blob/530bc70277779e81b4c666e7608a048a3b568df3/src/CompactSet.cc. Of course, I'll read any late answers and apply them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First impressions are very good.  You've taken advice from previous reviews and applied it well.  The code layout is clear and readable, and my comments are generally going to be very minor concerns.

I would have liked to see some tests with this.  Or even just a demonstration program that uses the class.

---

When we default-initialise an iterator, its `i` member is undefined:

> ```
>     const std::vector<bool> *bits = nullptr;
>     size_type i;
>     
>     iterator() = default;
> ```

---

I don't think we need all of these iterator comparisons:

> ```
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const iterator &other) const { return this->i == other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i != other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator<(const iterator &other) const { return this->i < other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator<=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i <= other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator>(const iterator &other) const { return this->i > other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] bool operator>=(const iterator &other) const { return this->i >= other.i; }
>     [[nodiscard]] auto operator<=>(const iterator &other) const { return this->i <=> other.i; }
> ```

The idea of `<=>` is that we just implement that one and the compiler can synthesize all the others as necessary.

---

Slight simplification of post-increment and post-decrement: replace `++copy; return copy;` with `return ++copy;`.  It's arguable whether that's an improvement (some style guides discourage side-effects in such expressions).

You could even go with `{ return ++iterator{*this}; }` but I'd argue that's too obscure.

---

I think that `i` needs to be able to represent a value that's one greater than the set size, in order to create an end iterator, so we can't just use `value_type`.  Or we could disallow creating containers that could include a maximum value.  On balance, I think I'm comfortable with the choice you made to always use the vector's size type for this.

---

I like that we test we actually have a bidirectional iterator using `static_assert()`.  I didn't think of that, though I probably would have if writing unit tests.

---

The set's `operator!=()` should by synthesizable from `==`.  I can't remember whether that's automatic or whether we actually need to write `bool operator!=(const CompactSet&) const = default`.

---

We could be more compatible with standard set if we implement the `insert()` overloads that accept a "hint" iterator (we can just ignore the hint, of course).

---

I like the name change for `unsafe_insert()`.  It's a good balance between safety and optimisation now.

I wonder how much it would hurt to make a safe version, that computes the overlap size as it adds.  It would look something like this:

```
template<std::unsigned_integral T>
void CompactSet<T>::insert(const CompactSet &other)
{
    size_type intersection_size = 0;
    auto combine = [&intersection_size](auto a, auto b){
        intersection_size += a & b;
        return a | b;
    };
    std::ranges::transform(bits, other.bits, bits.begin(), combine);
    size_ += other.size_ - intersection_size;
}
```

We might want to reject insertion of sets containing elements beyond our `max_size()`, rather than simply dropping those values?

Of course, if we had access to the bit vector's underlying representation, we could use bitwise operations (and `std::popcount()` or `std::bitset::count()` for counting the intersection size of each block of bits).

---

`emplace(Args&&... args)` might be overkill.  The only valid `Args...` is a single integer, so I think that could just be `emplace(value_type)`.  Similarly for `emplace_hint()`.

---

It may be useful to declare `swap()` (in particular) with `noexcept`.  This can help generic functions provide the strong exception guarantee.

---

These asserts in the constructor perhaps ought always to be executed and throw an exception (rather than being absent when `NDEBUG` is defined):

> ```
> assert(capacity == 0 || capacity - 1 <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
> assert(capacity <= std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max());  // Otherwise, iterators won't work.
> ```

(Even though this is a template, it's possible for instantiations of it to be compiled separately from client code.)

Comment: That's a good point about the tests. After reading the program again, I can see that `equal_range`, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` won't work if `max_size() == 0`, which is a valid state of the object. I have general tests which run the program for various inputs and compare output to the expected one. Before the review, this approach was enough to test the entire program but now I have functions I don't use :-/

Comment: On the other hand, maybe calling those functions should be defined behavior only value values less than `max_size`.

Comment: I've tried to remove all comparisons from the iterator beside the `operator<=>` but this breaks the compilation. The compiler complains about lack of `operator!=` so it seems that the trick with implying other comparisons from <=> doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I see that equality operators cannot be defaulted from the spaceship operator because this has high chance to create poorly optimized code (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58780829/3052438). However, implying the `operator!=` from the `operator==` does work as well as all the inequality operators from the `operator<=>`. I'll remove the unnecessary operators.

Comment: You missed the 2nd `insert()`. It accepts a hint.

Comment: I'm not sure if we need `insert(const CompactSet &other)` since we can use `insert(const InputIt first, const InputIt last)` in this context.

Comment: I consider using the `emplace(Args&&... args)` a futureproofing. It they ever add something weird, like a constructor for `unsigned` that takes an array of bytes, this code will still work.

Comment: I did miss the second `insert()`.  Apologies.  Maybe that's a sign that in section of code it's hard to pick out the signatures clearly?  I don't have a good suggestion for laying it out any better, though...